# How to draw huge high-dimensional normally distributed vectors in a memory-efficient way

Tags: r, normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

I would like to simulate a few hundred multivariate normally distributed vectors $H$ of dimension $10^6$ with covariance matrix $\Sigma$, preferrably in R. The individual entries of $\Sigma$ are provided by a function and can easily be computed.

However, already when I try to draw a vector of dimension $10^4$, $\Sigma$ has $10^8$ entries which takes up approx. 750MB of RAM. 
For dimension $10^6$, $\Sigma$ would have $10^{12}$ entries, resulting in a RAM need of approx 7.5 terabytes which my machine does not provide.

---

As far as I know, to compute multivariate normal vectors usually a cholesky decomposition $\Sigma = A A^T $ has to be computed ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Computational_methods)) for which usually the whole covariance matrix needs to be loaded in RAM at once.

---

Are there any approaches/algorithms/methods for drawing random vectors, where not the whole covariance matrix has to be loaded in RAM at once?

---

**EDIT**: The vector we are talking about is a centered gaussian random process $H(u,v)$ on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with covariance function 
\begin{align}
C((u, v), (u',v')) = &\frac{vv'}{uu'}\min(u,u') - \frac{v'}{u'}\min(v.u')\\
&\frac{v}{u}\min(u,v') + \min(v,v').
\end{align}

The covariance seems to be sparse in some sense (approx. 30% of the matrix entries are very close to 0), but I can not see a general sparsity pattern (i.e. there often are high covariances even if $u$ and $v$ are far apart from each other).

When drawing from this gaussian process distribution, I have to discretize the interval, i.e. I get a normally distributed vector with an entry for every $(u,v)\in\{(k/N,l/N): k, l = 1, \dotsc, N\}$. So for $N = 1000$ I get a vector of dimension $1000^2 = 10^6 $.

---

**EDIT2**:
I need to draw these samples because I need to estimate the quantiles of the related process 
$$\mathcal{H}(w) = \sup_{0\leq u\leq v \leq w}| H(u,v)|.$$
These quantiles are needed in a larger statistical framework to estimate changepoints of locally stationary processes as described in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1425398506).

Comment: One of your best hopes would be that the structure of $\Sigma$ is special.  What can you tell us about that?

Comment: Be aware that this looks like a question about software ("Are there any other approaches or packages to this..."), which are generally considered off topic here. This may be on topic on [SO], though. If you can turn this into an explicitly *statistical* question, please do so.

Comment: Hmm, even though I am asking for a package recommendation, I believe that at the core this question can only be solved by providing a algorithm/a mathematical method which is designed in a clever way which in the end does not depend on a particular programming language.

Comment: I have clarified the question a little, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Can say more about the context and your eventual goal (why do you want to sample)? When working with gaussian processes for big datasets, one typically has to resort to approximations. This will depend on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have added some more details, not sure if this is helpful at all. So if I understand your comment correctly, there is no straightforward/general algorithm to sample gaussian processes with many time-points? Can you recommend literature that deals with techniques to sample from a gaussian process?

Comment: Does your resulting estimates completely deteriorate if you use 100 points instead? Do you have a feel for the uncertainty as you vary the number of points?

Comment: what are u and v? and if they're Gaussian then how come are they bounded on [0,1]? can you give a small example of your matrix and numbers generated from it? maybe for a very small grid 3x3 or something like that

Comment: $u$ and $v$ are the indices of the gaussian process. (Often a gaussian process depends on one-dimensional time points $t \inT$.  Here the time points are two-dimensional tuples $(u,v)$, but in fact a gaussian process can take any kind of mathematical object as index. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process#Definition for instance. In our case, the index set $T$ is replaced by $[0,1] \times [0,1]$).

Comment: @Forgottenscience: The results are systematically too small if my grid is not fine enough due to taking a supremum of the process, see my follow-up question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467955/how-to-simulate-the-supremum-of-a-gaussian-process